# Object.values throws TypeError in IE browser- How to polyfill it?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, babeljs, babel-polyfill

In my ember app,I am using `Object.values` method, which is throwing the below error in IE browser.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'values' TypeError: Object
>   doesn't support property or method 'values'

In my package.json

```
"ember-cli-babel": "^6.3.0"
```

my target.js file shows,

```
module.exports = {
  browsers: [
    'ie 9',
    'last 1 Chrome versions',
    'last 1 Firefox versions',
    'last 1 Safari versions'
  ]
};
```

I am using

```
ember-cli: 2.13.3
node: 6.3.1
```

`Object.values` is supported [only in EDGE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). How do I polyfill this in my ember project?.
Similarly for `String.endsWith` I just the included the polyfill in `app.js` file. Here I want to use babel-polyfill so that it will automatically polyfill for the browser I mentioned in `target.js`

Comment: [That same link you have about the support also has a section about polyfilling it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Polyfill)

Comment: This file https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js I tried then I got `Reflect` is not defined error. So I dont want to polyfill each time I use newer features, I just want to ember-cli to take care of it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

ember-cli-babel comes with polyfill support configuration. I should have gone through their docs. I wasn't aware that the below configuration will do the magic.

```
// ember-cli-build.js

var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  'ember-cli-babel': {
    includePolyfill: true
  }
});
```

https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel#polyfill

Comment: I mentioned in `ie 9` in target.js file so I thought ember-cli will do automatically polyfill. but that's not true but then it requires `includePolyfill: true` settings.. I dont know the reason for why do I have to mention `ie 9` in target.js file?